# NOT IN operation on realm database using javascript

Tags: javascript, realm

> i want to make "NOT IN" operation on realm database how to  make it .

```
   let  user = db.user.find().WHERE id NOT IN ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: I kinda wonder that you could probably do `NOT ID IN (....)`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no `NOT IN` in Realm, but you can do it quite easy and without it:

```
        val query = it.where(User::class.java)
        arrayOf("1", "2", "3").forEach { query.notEqualTo("id", it) }
        val res = query.findAll()
```

*I didn't run this code, but I think idea is trivial and should be clear*

Comment: Javascript. Not kotlin.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Idea is the same.

Comment: The JS query language is totally different -_-

Comment: yaa @EpicPandaForce is right  js code is quit  different  then java code and  this code  will not work  in javascript